# Can I compile an app in i386 mode using emscripten?

Tags: javascript, llvm, 32bit-64bit, emscripten, webassembly

I have a legacy C application that does not work when compiled in a 64-bit environment because it depends on the size of pointers and other data types being 32-bits.

Is there an emscripten flag I can use to compile the program in 32-bit mode or do I need to port it first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emscripten and asm.js use 32-bit pointers already, it's the only mode they support. It's set by [this line](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten-fastcomp-clang/blob/271ce598c3d1fe74efadc254f5be1b57edea9f41/lib/Basic/Targets.cpp#L7129) in Emscripten's "fastcomp" fork of clang.